Differences and usages of "Student Fee" and "Student Fees"
What are the differences and usages of Student Fee and Student Fees?
I have used words like Student Fees/Fee, Fees Collection, and Fee Collection. So I would like someone to explain if there is any difference and give some usages of them.

Could you give one or more examples of the context that these would appear in?

In general, if something said "Student Fee" I would assume that there was one fee - probably some sort of flat rate (consistent cost), perhaps for student activities. If someone said "Student Fees" I would assume that there were multiple fees charged for different things, such that a bill might look like "Student Fees: Book Fee - $50 Activities Fee - $200 Enrollment Fee - $30" etc.

"Fee" is singular, "fees" is plural; that's a difference. Please edit to explain more about what you don't understand or focus the question more. Voting to close as unclear.
